# multiple access to shell script

Tags: shell

I'm converting doc files to pdf using shell command in PHP. Each user can convert its file to PHP any time. Is it possible that multiple users can access my converter at the same time to convert their files ?

I'm using CENTOS on dedicated server.

Answer (score 1):

Let's define the likely layers of your php conversion utility.

```
  terminal # user enters commands here, sees output

      shell  # the terminal automatically starts a shell process
             # so users can type commands and get work done

          /path/to/your/conversion/tool.php  doc1.doc doc1.pdf 
             # here is the user, accessing your script. 
             # one solution to conversions is to allow for 1 input and 1 ouput file
             # I have done that to keep things simple, your solution may be different

             phpcode shell("externalconverter", "doc1.doc","doc1.pdf", "/path/to/tmpWrkSpace"?)                 
             # again, a guess, your php is asking to execute a external command
             # and we're passing the arguments

                  "externalconverter" "doc1.doc" "doc1.pdf"  tmp="/path/to/tmpWrkSpace" 
                  # again, a guess
```

So, it depends if you or the  exteranlconverter create any temporary files with static (or  non-unique) names.
I.e. 2 users launch program at same time with different filenames, are any temporary files created that have the exact same name? Probably not, but that sort of thing does happen AND is worth checking for ahead of time.

To confirm you're safe, set up a test with 2 terminal windows, type in both commands ahead of time, using a .doc file created specially for this test AND that will not matter,  execute both commands at the same time (as fast as possible). You'll need a file that is big enough (or in any case) to take a long time to process that you're certain both files are being processed at the same time.

In general, assuming a Linux/Unix OS, most programs allow multiple copies to run at the same time. But testing is your best defense.

If this doesn't answer your question, consider using the above outline to edit your question to show us the heirarchy of the elements in your conversion tool.

IHTH.